# Apache modify Authorization header after authentication

Tags: apache

I have to change the Authorization header after mod_auth_basic has verified the credentials.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a (small) Apache module. No general purpose directive can edit headers at that stage of processing. If you use 2.4, you could implement it in Lua and run it via mod_lua.

You probably wan to run during the "fixups" hook.